# Filtering a list from dropdownlist

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a list of rows I'm returning, I would like to filter my results with a dropdownlist:

```
//auto-populated
 <span>User: </span>
 <select id="ddlUser" class="form-control"> 
     <option selected disabled="true">--- Select User---</option>
     @foreach (var userin User)
     {
         <option id="@user.UserID">@user.UserName</option>
     }
 </select>

 <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
         <tr><th>User ID</th>
             <th>User Name</th>
             <th>First Name</th>
             <th>Last Name</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         @foreach (var user in Users)
         {
             <tr>
                 <td>@user.UserID</td>
                 <td>@user.UserName</td>
                 <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                 <td>@user.LastName</td>
             </tr>
         }
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

How can I do this in Blazor Server??

Comment: The foreach should filter based on the ddlUser value. So something like  `@foreach (var user in Users.Where(x=>x.UserID == ddlUserValue)`

Comment: Well, you're not really "filtering."  You're just selecting a particular person.  I certainly hope you don't have multiple people with the same UserID!

Comment: Well, you're not really "filtering" right now.  You're just selecting a particular person, since you are selecting on ID values, and so your filteredUsers collection should never be more than one item.  If you really want a filter, then use a `text input`, and filter with something like `filteredUsers = Users.Where(u=> u.UserName.Contains(filterText));`  No need to use a `select`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to bind the `<select>` element's value to a field. e.g. `selectedUser`

Then, you can use the `selectedUser` to create a filtered users collection which you can use to add your filter conditions. e.g. `filteredUsers`

Now whenever the selection changes the filtered users will change based on the filter condtions.
e.g. In the example below if nothing is selected all users will be shown.

**Edit:** changing the example to show more of a filtering behaviour, now it filters based on selected users Last Name.

```
@using System.Linq

<span>User: </span>
<!-- @bind to selectedUser -->
<select @bind="_selectedUser" class="form-control"> 
    <option selected value="">--- Select User---</option>
    @foreach (var user in _users)
    {
        <option value="@user.UserID">@user.UserName</option>
    }
</select>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>User ID</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- use filtered _users instead of _users -->
        @foreach (var user in _filteredUsers) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.UserID</td>
                <td>@user.UserName</td>
                <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                <td>@user.LastName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    string _selectedUser;
    List<User> _users = new List<User>();
    List<User> _filteredUsers
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedUser))
            {
                return _users;
            }
            else
            {
                User selectedUser = _users.Find(u => u.UserID == _selectedUser);
                return _users.Where(u => u.LastName == selectedUser.LastName).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Snippet demo](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wxPaYzlc39THUQm632)

Comment: Does this really make sense IRL though?  When are you ever going to have anything other than an individual record returned?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Very true, I'm just trying to show the OP how he needs to use @bind to get the selection and how it can be used against another element. Judging by how he's using `id` in select I'm assuming that's the part he doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others. you're not filtering anything using an Id.  As I assume this is an example, I've changed the context to a Continent/Country context to provide a working answer.

I've added a data provider to make this more realistic.  This emulates a data service that you would use to get your filtered list.  What you use as the initial list is up to you.  In many cases, we present no list as the items list you are filtering may be huge!

```cs
@page "/"
<div class="row">

<div class="col-6">
    <h6>Pre Net7.0</h6>
    <InputSelect TValue="string" class="form-control mb-3" Value="_continentFilter" ValueChanged="SelectionUpdated" ValueExpression="() => _continentFilter">
        @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_continentFilter))
        {
            <option selected disabled> --- Select a Continent--- </option>
        }
        @foreach (var continent in CountryProvider.Continents)
        {
            <option value="@continent">@continent</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <h6> Net7.0</h6>
    <select class="form-control mb-3" @bind="_continentFilter" @bind:after="SelectUpdated">
        @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_continentFilter))
        {
            <option selected disabled> --- Select a Continent--- </option>
        }
        @foreach (var continent in CountryProvider.Continents)
        {
            <option value="@continent">@continent</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Continent</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @if (_filteredCountries is null || _filteredCountries.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">No Filter Selected</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            @foreach (var country in _filteredCountries)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@country.Continent</td>
                    <td>@country.CountryName</td>
                </tr>
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    private string? _continentFilter;
    private IEnumerable<Country> _filteredCountries = Enumerable.Empty<Country>();

    private void SelectUpdated()
    {
        _filteredCountries = CountryProvider.GetCountries(_continentFilter);
    }

    private void SelectionUpdated(string? value)
    {
        _continentFilter = value;
        _filteredCountries = CountryProvider.GetCountries(_continentFilter);
    }

    public record Country(string Continent, string CountryName);

    // Static so it emulates like a service
    public static class CountryProvider
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> Continents => _countries.Select(item => item.Continent).Distinct().OrderBy(item => item);

        public static IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries(string? continent)
        {
            return continent is null
            ? _countries
            : _countries.Where(item => item.Continent.Equals(continent));
        }

        private static List<Country> _countries = new()
        {
        new("Europe", "UK"),
        new("Europe", "France"),
        new("Europe", "Spain"),
        new("Oceana", "Australia"),
        new("Oceana", "Cook Islands"),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason its not liking me to add @bind:after="SelectionUpdated" message is: 'Runtime Helpers' does not contain definition for 'CreateInferredBindSetter'

Comment: That's Net7.0, which you obviously aren't using.  I've updated my answer to cover pre Net7.0.

Comment: I changed it. Here is the error I'm getting in Chrome: Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@bind::after' is not a valid attribute name.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@bind::after' is not a valid attribute name.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: What version of Net are you using?