MudBlazor MudSelect incorrectly displays first item in list instead of selected values when primary selection is made
I'm working on a Blazor application using MudBlazor, and I'm encountering an issue with a MudSelect component used for selecting secondary muscle groups. The problem occurs when a primary muscle group is selected in a separate component.
Here's the scenario:
I have two MudSelect components: one for selecting a primary muscle group and another for selecting multiple secondary muscle groups.
When no primary muscle group is selected, the secondary MudSelect works correctly, displaying all selected values as a comma-separated string when the dropdown is closed.
However, when a primary muscle group is selected, the secondary MudSelect's display (when closed) always shows the first item in the list(IE "Shoulders"), regardless of which secondary muscle groups are actually selected.
If I open the secondary MudSelect dropdown, I can see that the correct items are selected; the issue is only with the display when the dropdown is closed.
Here's a simplified version of my MudSelect for secondary muscle groups:
<MudSelect T="MuscleGroups" Label="Secondary Muscle Groups" MultiSelection="true"
           @bind-SelectedValues="SecondaryMuscleGroups"
           Variant="Variant.Outlined">
    @foreach (var muscleGroup in AvailableSecondaryMuscleGroups)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@muscleGroup">@muscleGroup.ToString()</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Working sample of problem at TryMudblazor:https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYmeOivrMYvMBnYf
I have debated with both ChatGTP, Claude and Github copilot but always end up going down a rabbit hole that leads to complex code that don't solve the problem..

Take a look at this answer based on a Continent/Country context.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77235328/13065781

Had a look at your snippet. I think the main thing causing the issue is the casting to string using ToString() in this line <MudSelectItem Value="@muscleGroup">@muscleGroup.ToString()</MudSelectItem>. Although I did make a bunch of changes to your snippet.
A lot of logic was tied to the actual property which was very confusing, especially when you need to keep track of the flow of your components with respect to Blazor's lifecycle. I'd reccomend using the lifecycle methods such as OnInitialised, OnAfterRender etc. To handle initialising properties & fields.
<MudPaper Class="p-4 max-w-screen-sm mx-auto" Elevation="2">
    <MudForm @ref="form" Model="@newExercise" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
         <MudSelect T="MuscleGroups" Label="Primary Muscle Group" Value="_primaryMuscleGroup" ValueChanged="OnPrimaryMuscleGroupChanged" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
            @foreach (var muscleGroup in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MuscleGroups)))
            {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@((MuscleGroups)muscleGroup)">@muscleGroup.ToString()</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
        <MudSelect T="MuscleGroups" Label="Secondary Muscle Groups" MultiSelection="true"
                    SelectedValues="@_secondaryMuscleGroups"
                    SelectedValuesChanged="OnSecondaryMuscleGroupsChanged"
                    Variant="Variant.Outlined">

            @foreach (var muscleGroup in SelectableSecGroups)
            {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@muscleGroup"/>
            }
        </MudSelect>
    </MudForm>
</MudPaper>

@code {

    private MudForm form; 

    private Exercise newExercise;
    private MuscleGroups _primaryMuscleGroup;
    private HashSet<MuscleGroups> _secondaryMuscleGroups;
    private List<MuscleGroups> SelectableSecGroups;

    protected override void OnInitialized(){
        newExercise = new();
        _primaryMuscleGroup = newExercise.PrimaryMuscleGroup;
        _secondaryMuscleGroups = new HashSet<MuscleGroups>();
        SelectableSecGroups = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MuscleGroups))
               .Cast<MuscleGroups>().ToList();
        UpdateAvailableSecondaryTargetedMuscles();
    }
 
    private void OnSecondaryMuscleGroupsChanged(IEnumerable<MuscleGroups> newSecondaryMuscleGroups) {
        _secondaryMuscleGroups.Clear();
        _secondaryMuscleGroups.UnionWith(newSecondaryMuscleGroups);
    }

    private void OnPrimaryMuscleGroupChanged(MuscleGroups newPrimaryMuscleGroup)
    {
        _primaryMuscleGroup = newPrimaryMuscleGroup;
        UpdateAvailableSecondaryTargetedMuscles();
    }

    private void UpdateAvailableSecondaryTargetedMuscles()
    {
        if(_primaryMuscleGroup != MuscleGroups.Default) // assumed default should always be selectable
        {
            SelectableSecGroups = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MuscleGroups))
                .Cast<MuscleGroups>()
                .Where(mg => mg != _primaryMuscleGroup).ToList();
        }
    }
  
    public class Exercise
    {
        
        public MuscleGroups PrimaryMuscleGroup { get; set; } = MuscleGroups.Default;

        public List<MuscleGroups> SecondaryMuscleGroups { get; set; } = new List<MuscleGroups>();
    
    }
    public enum MuscleGroups
    {
        Shoulders,
        Chest,
        Biceps,
        Triceps,
        Forearms,
        Abs,
        Legs,
        Core,
        Back,
        Calves,
        Glutes,
        Neck,
        Default // Fallback for exercises that don’t fit neatly into other categories
    }
}

Demo  MudBlazor Snippet
